# My website doesn't work properly on smaller

Tags: html, css, web

I'm having a problem with my website. I have a div with animated text on the right side of the page and a div with some text on the left side. Everything works fine with 1920x1080 resolution but when I make the page smaller or change the resolution, the div with animated text just doesn't stay in its own position and pushes the left div to the bottom. I don't know how to fix this. I want to make that both divs will resize automatically on smaller resolution or when someone makes resize the window to fit the size of the screen.

**How it looks with 1920x1080 resolution:**

[image: 1920x1080 resolution]

**How it looks like with 1600x1024 resolution:**
[image]

**And here when I'm resizing the window:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">
    <head>
        <title>Little Hero | A simple indie game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="ikona.png">
        <meta name="description" content="Small indie game developed by one person using pygame module in python focusing on rogue-like experience.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="PC, game, pixel, indie, Steam, python, pygame, development">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="language" content="english">
        <meta name="author" content="all: censored; censored">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow, snippet, archive">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <div class="informacni_odkazy">
                        <li><a href="" title="Learn more about this game">LEARN MORE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="Check updates">UPDATES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="Where you can contact me">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="herni_odkazy">
                        <li><a href="" title="Register">SIGN UP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="Buy the game">PLAY NOW</a></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="pozadi_nadpisu">
            <div class="animovany_text">
                <p><span></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="nadpisy_stranky">
                <h1>Little Hero</h1>
                <h2>Dive into an epic adventure with a rogue-like experience.</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="formular">
            <h3>Why sign up?</h3>
            <p>Everyone who sign-ups for this game gives me feedback to continue in development. Once this game is finished I will be sending a few free copies randomly among the registered emails.</p>
            <form>
                <div class="email">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="duvod">
                    <label for="duvod">Why I'm looking forward to this game</label>
                    <textarea name="duvod" id="duvod" cols="50" rows="10" minlength="20" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="tlacitko">
                    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
        <footer>The game is still in progress, once the game is finished everyone registered will receive an email about the release date.</footer>

    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
}

.informacni_odkazy {
  float: left;
}

.informacni_odkazy li {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.informacni_odkazy a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.informacni_odkazy a:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid rgb(1, 174, 255);
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.herni_odkazy {
  float: right;
}

.herni_odkazy li {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.herni_odkazy a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0.2rem solid rgb(1, 174, 255);
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.herni_odkazy a:hover {
  background: rgb(1, 174, 255);
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

.pozadi_nadpisu {
  background-image: url(pozadi_1.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 35rem;
  padding-bottom: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15rem;
}

.nadpisy_stranky {
  float: left;
  border: 0.2rem solid black;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background: rgba(209, 192, 192, 0.25);
  width: 70rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  margin-left: 20rem;
  text-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem black;
}

.nadpisy_stranky h1 {
  color: rgb(116, 164, 253);
  font-size: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.nadpisy_stranky h2 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.863);
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.animovany_text {
  float: right;
}

.animovany_text p {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 0.5rem solid black;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 50rem;
  margin-top: 8.5rem;
  margin-right: 20rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 12rem;
}

span:before {
  content: "";
  animation: animuj infinite 8s;
}

@keyframes animuj {
  0% {
    content: "LEARN";
  }
  25% {
    content: "FIGHT";
  }
  50% {
    content: "EXPLORE";
  }
  75% {
    content: "IMPROVE";
  }
  100% {
    content: "SURVIVE!";
  }
}

.formular {
  font-size: 5rem;
  background-image: url(pozadi.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 15rem;
  padding-bottom: 15rem;
  border-top: 0.5rem solid black;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.formular form {
  border: 0.5rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.377);
  padding: 5rem 1rem 5rem 1rem;
  width: 90rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.formular h3,
p {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.formular h3 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.email {
  border-bottom: 0.3rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 70rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.email label {
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.email input {
  width: 37rem;
  height: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.duvod {
  border-bottom: 0.3rem solid black;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 70rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.duvod label {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.duvod textarea {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 70rem;
  resize: none;
  border: 0.2rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.tlacitko {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.tlacitko button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0.35rem solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: none;
  width: 70rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.tlacitko button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(46, 43, 43, 0.85);
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**The two divs you are looking for are:**

**.nadpisy_stranky
.nadpisy_stranky h1
.nadpisy_stranky h2**

**.animovany_text
.animovany_text p**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, before I didn't have it with floats but with position absolute on the right div but the result was the same.

Comment: I recommend to take a look at [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) this is pretty much custom CSS dependent on certain constraints (eg. screen size). Your code as it is currently doesn't resize anything, did you expect it to do it automatically?